# Proof of Weierstrass Theorem (case of Stone-Weierstrass)

Tags: real-analysis

This maybe out there somewhere, but I can't seem to find an exact one. I am trying to prove that if X is an interval [a,b], F = C(x) (the continuous functions), and A = P(x) (the polynomials), then P(x) is dense in F.

My instructor called this the Weierstrass Theorem, which he said is a special case of Stone-Weierstrass.

The metric is D(f,g) = Sup |f(x) - g(x)|.

This has to be out there somewhere, I just can't find an exact one. When you type in "Weierstrass Theorem" a lot comes up. Can anyone help me prove this or point out where I can find a proof? Mainly I'm having trouble getting started.

Comment: I've found this: https://mast.queensu.ca/~speicher/Section14.pdf

Comment: by the way, it was the first result googling "proof polynomials are dense" - there are quite a few other proofs out there

Comment: Try Weierstrauss Approximation Theorem for the non-general case (i.e. on closed interval $[a,b]$).